# Ansible get_url Fails If Destination File Does Not Exist

Tags: ansible, geturl

When using get_url, it fails if the destination file does not exist locally. If I us vi and create the file with nothing in it, then the call works and the file is replaced. I added force: yes to encourage it to write out the file, but every attempt failed until I created a dummy file.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

```
---
- name: Download HashiCorp Installation Archive File
  hosts: 127.0.0.1

  vars:
    vault:
      distro:  'linux'
      version: '1.5.4'
    user:
      group: 'rcouch'
      name:  'rcouch'
  
  tasks:

    # https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/1.5.4/vault_1.5.4_linux_amd64.zip
    - name: Download Binary
      get_url:
        url:      "https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/{{ vault.version }}/vault_{{ vault.version }}_{{ vault.distro }}_amd64.zip"
        checksum: "sha256:https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/{{ vault.version }}/vault_{{ vault.version }}_SHA256SUMS"
        force:    yes
        dest:     "vault_{{ vault.version }}_{{ vault.distro }}_amd64.zip"
        owner:    "{{ user.group }}"
        group:    "{{ user.name }}"
        mode:     0755
      register: vault_download
  
    - name: Display Vault Download
      debug:
        msg:
        - "vault_download: {{ vault_download }}"
```

Comment: Can you add exact failure ?

Comment: P.... , seshadri_c had the answer below. But I will remember to include the error message in future posts. Thank you, Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get_url` module takes an absolute path in `dest`. A small excerpt from the [module's page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/get_url_module.html). Try an absolute path like `/tmp` or `./`.

> | `dest` | Absolute path of where to download the file to. |

```yaml
  tasks:
  - get_url:
      url: https://releases.hashicorp.com/vault/1.5.4/vault_1.5.4_linux_amd64.zip
      dest: ./vault_1.5.4_linux_amd64.zip
```

Comment: seshadri_c, Thank you! That was exactly it. I need to slow down while I "RTFM"!

The absolute path worked perfectly. Thank you, Rob